# Run application in a full screen(F11) mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

```
var  elem = document.documentElement;
           // var elem = document.getElementById('.body');
          //var elem = $('.sapUiBody');
            //alert(elem);
            rfs =
                elem.requestFullScreen
                || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen
                || elem.mozRequestFullScreen
                || elem.msRequestFullscreen;

                rfs.call(elem);
```

I want to run my application in a full screen mode so I have mapped the above code to my press event function of the login button. But the problem is when the after login the full screen mode exits due to change in view. Is it possible to use the view through out the application with using it once in the login button action or is it possible to implement the same with out using any event. And for that matter is there any openui5 way to implement it.

Comment: Are you dealing with single application or many applications in `shell` ?

Comment: need more details about login button. are there some code execution when you click the button? maybe you could use timeouts to achieve such functionality.

Comment: @Jai, In case of OP, he seems to having many grids for multiple applications.. and once he is navigated from app to app, `full-screen` is exited to normal view..

Comment: @RayonDabre Its a single page application but the thing is login screen is not part of the single page application. after login you are redirected to another page and from there pn application is single screen.

Comment: trigger full screen at the spa layer too

Comment: @madalinivascu  thing is the above code is only functional inside an event and not any normal function . But to make it functional I need to give a button in my view to make it work but I want it by default and not upon any action like press or click.

Comment: the page load event doesn't do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fire the event automatically, but you can `addeventlistener` on `btn` to trigger it.
Check this API [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen)

Comment: Eventually I am doing the same thing but the thing is my application and application's login page both are different screens so when until the redirection happens it remains in full screen mode in login page and once it redirects to welcome page full screen exits.

Comment: As its redirect to another page it will exit fullscreen mode. 
May you can apply it when the user login...

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the above code at DOMContentLoaded on the SPA page

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  var elem = document.documentElement,
    rfs = elem.requestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen;
  rfs.call(elem);
});
```

Comment: @madalinivascu  Even though the listener invokes itself just fine still it somehow is not working.

Comment: @RayonDabre  I have a main jsp where in the rest are tabs in my application so I would be able to apply it in main then it would work for all the application.

Comment: if the page does not remain fullscreen then you may have a js script that  may interfere

Answer (score 0):

The above code will only work in case of some events such as click/select/key etc but there is a work around:

1. go to `about:config` in the browser.
2. search for `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only` is make it `false`. By default it is true.
3. Then use above code anywhere in the code it will just run fine.

But the making these changes in the `config` is not recommended for certain security reasons.